# forms-mode in Emacs, what is its purpose, has anyone used it?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I found something interesting called forms-mode in Emacs, I just can't figure out how or what its purpose is. Is it used by any major mode in Emacs?

Answer (score 6):

`Forms: (forms).               Emacs package for editing data bases by filling in forms.`

> Forms mode is an Emacs major mode for working with simple textual data
>   bases in a forms-oriented manner.  In Forms mode, the information in
>   these files is presented in an Emacs window in a user-defined format,
>   one record at a time.  The user can view records or modify their
>   contents.
>
> Forms mode is not a simple major mode, but requires two files to do
>   its job: a control file and a data file.  The data file holds the
>   actual data to be presented.  The control file describes how to present
>   it.

For full documentation, start here:
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(forms) Top")` <kbd>RET</kbd>
(or <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> `Forms` <kbd>RET</kbd>)

Also see the commentary at:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `forms` <kbd>RET</kbd>

And there's an example form provided in the same directory, so from the library you can do this to see it in action:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> `forms-d2.el` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `forms-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>